# Alignment issue with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a 2 row layout, with 1 column in the first row, and three columns in the second row. The text is aligned left in the one column, and the three columns in the second row are all center aligned like so:

[image]

What I want to do is to somehow align the text in the one column with the left edge of the first item in the 3 column layout, but I'm not sure if this is possible? (at least not without using js). Is there a simple way to do this using the bootstrap classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the top text inside the same container as 'Centered 1', and then move it up using position:absolute. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avgh4x67/.

HTML:

```
<div id='above'></div>
<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <div>
      Centered 1
      <div id='centered-1-aligned'>aligned</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <div>Centered 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <div>Centered 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#above {height: 80px; border: solid 3px red; margin-bottom: 10px;}
.col-sm-4 {text-align:center; border: solid 3px red; }
.col-sm-4 > div {display:inline-block;}
#centered-1-aligned {text-align: left; position: absolute; top: -80px;}
```

Comment: That's actually a very good idea. The only trouble is the size of the content can change, so I need something that works with all content - I could only do the above if I knew it's fixed size. Thanks though

Comment: @alimac83 Do you mean that the content's height may change?

Comment: yes, and if I do position: absolute then it'll break the space required too